# Deciding parameters of DBSCAN Algo for Tweet clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am trying to cluster tweets to detect breaking news. I am using DBSCAN as the clustering technique. I am unable to arrive at good values of epsilon and min_sample_points. To cluster the tweets i am making batches of 2000 tweets and applying the clustering algo on it. For feauture extraction i am using the tf-idf vectorizer from scikit.learn package. Using max_df= 0.6 and min_df= 5 and bi-grams as parameters for the vectorizer. The result at large is showing most tweets as outliers or many random tweets into a single cluster. Example of values i have used - eps =0.2 and min_samples = 8. Also i am avoiding K-means algorithm since the no of clusters(k) cannot be foresighted for this problem and the shape of the cluster may not necessarily be spherical.

Comment: I seemed to have solved my own problem.The problem was that the data source for me was the twitter streaming API which only provides about 1% of the total tweets in a given period.The tweets in a batch of around 2000 tweets are largely very different.Keeping the min_sample points=1 solves the problem and an eps of around 0.5-0.8 is good .Now to consider a cluster worthy u can ignore the clusters with size 1.According to your problem you can have a threshold for the cluster size to mark it as worthy cluster. The key to choose eps lay in viewing the sparse matrix which is input to clusteringAlgo

Answer (score 1):

For breaking news, there are much better approaches than clustering.

Text data and in particular Twitter is incredibly noisy. Many Tweets are just complete nonsense. But the main problem is that they are *too short*. If you only have a few words, there is too little data to measure distance. "The car hit a wall." and "A car on Wall street" have very similar words (based on TF-IDF) yet they have very different meaning.

So I'm not surprised this does not work well. It's actually not the clustering which "fails" but your distance function.

Comment: Could you then suggest alternate distance measures?..I am filtering the tweets to get only news tweets using a multinomial naives bayes which is showing an accuracy of 89%..the clustering is being done only on these news tweets.

Comment: I think it is a problem of the data, not the distance measure.